# How to click on this button?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

How to click this button?

> input class="submit special" type="submit" value="» Submit"/>

I tried but failed:

> var elems = wb.Document.GetElementByTagName("input");
>
> foreach(HtmlElement elem in elems){
>
>  if(elem.GetAttribute("class") == "submit"){
>
>     elem.InvokeMember("click");
>
>  }
>
> }

Comment: Not familiar with C# web driver, but have worked extensively with python. My advice to you is to set a breakpoint and walk through this with a debugger. What does wb.Document.GetElementByTagName("input"); return? what is the class name for each element in the list?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

`class="submit special"` will *not* match the if-condition, which checks for *exactly* "submit" as a value.

Consider either matching the type,

```
elem.GetAttribute("type") == "submit"
```

or see if "submit" exists at all in the class attribute value,

```
elem.GetAttribute("class").Contains("submit") // or maybe "special"
```

(The code *may* need to guard for null values in the latter form.)

Comment: I am guessing that this is the problem as well

Answer (score 0):

Or use jquery

```
$("input.submit.special").click(function() {
    $({some id or class of the form sorrounding the submit button}).submit();
});
```

http://www.jquery.com to download the files